# With Vue-i18n, how to display nothing until messages are dynamically loaded?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

In our Vue app, we are dynamically loading our translations. Until they arrive from the server, our strings are displayed as the codes/expression.

Is there some way to tell `Vue-i18n` to default to blank if there are no messages loaded ? Or can I override something to return an empty string ?

Comment: I'd add some isLoaded bool that has some "spinner" logic and when the strings are loaded from the server I'd set the bool to true which removes the "spinner". As for the Vue-i18n approach I'd doubt that has something implemented for this, maybe with https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html you can manage it somehow.

Comment: you can set a default language if there is no translation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding `fallbackLocale` property in `VueI18n` initialization.

As in the below demo locale `ja` is not available, Hence, it loads the `fallbackLocale` (I added empty string in all the properties for default locale).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      tokyo: 'Tokyo',
      newyork: 'New York',
      london: 'London'
    }
  },
  default: {
    message: {
      tokyo: '',
      newyork: '',
      london: ''
    }
  }
}
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'ja',
  fallbackLocale: 'default',
  messages,
})
new Vue({
  i18n,
  data: {cities: ['tokyo', 'newyork', 'london']}
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-i18n/8.14.1/vue-i18n.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="city in cities"
      :key="city">
      {{city}}: {{ $t("message." + city) }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This would require me to first have a full list of all the messages, which I don't have until they get loaded from the server.

Comment: @Magmatic From server you will get the locale files but for default you can create by your own at client side only (which will contain all the literals with value as a empty string). So that it should load based on `fallbackLocale`